# How to obtain value from environment variable in React APP

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have a React app that is using npm to be build.

What I am trying to do is to obtain the *CURRENT_ENV* value that is injected using a configMap in the AKS cluster.

I made a run.sh script that is run as ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile. In the run.sh I am exporting the CURRENT_ENV to a REACT_APP_CURRENT_VARIABLE. The run.sh file looks like this:

```
export REACT_APP_CURRENT_ENV=${CURRENT_ENV}

npx serve -s build -l 3000
```

At the pod level I am able to see the values from CURRENT_ENV and REACT_APP_CURRENT_VARIABLE, but at code level `process.env.REACT_APP_CURRENT_ENV`is *undefined*

I need to use the value from CURRENT_ENV env variable in the code to change a label dynamically based on the env on which the app is deployed.

Comment: did you tried something like `REACT_APP_CURRENT_ENV=$REACT_APP_CURRENT_ENV  npx serve -s build -l 3000` and is the `npx` is root process?

Comment: @Adiii I tried what you suggested and is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `.env` file in your project directory. and add the environment variable to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to do that, because we are not using `.env` files to setup any of our resources(like databases, kafka, env variables, etc). All these are injected directly in the pod through configMaps

Comment: this might work https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#linux-macos-bash

Comment: I have already created a custom env variable named as `REACT_APP_CURRENT_ENV` which takes the value from `CURRENT_ENV`, but in the code, when I'm access the variable through `process.env.REACT_APP_CURRENT_ENV` I get undefined

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: I wasnt able to obtain the value of the ENV variable and I found a workaround using the hostname, which contains the env on which the application is deployed.

Comment: Can you post the founded workaround using the hostname as an answer for greater visibility of the community.